# Lie bracket question

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I am wondering if this is correct.

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two smooth vector fields which vanish at $p$: $X(p) = Y(p) = 0$. Also assume that $[X, Y](p) = 0$.

Is it true that the derivative of the commutator of the flows $\phi^{X}_t$ and $\phi^{Y}_t$ is identity at $p$,i.e

$d_p(\phi^{X}_t \circ \phi^{Y}_t \circ \phi^{X}_{-t} \circ \phi^{Y}_{-t}) = id$.